# cannot access staticmetaobject

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

I cannot access staticmetaobject and I dont know why. I would need some help.

Here is the code

The two errors are:

```
staticMetaObject is not a member of MainWIndow*
```

I feel like it has something to do with the list, but I'm not sure.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "form.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    Form<MainWindow*>* form;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    /*qDebug() << MainWindow::staticMetaObject.className();

    if (QString(MainWindow::staticMetaObject.className()) == QString("MainWindow")) {
        qDebug() << "test";
    }*/

    form = new Form<MainWindow*>(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    form->myFunc();
}
```

form.h

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class FormBase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FormBase() {}
};

template <typename T>
class Form : public FormBase, public QList<T>
{
public:
    Form(T a)
    {
        QList<T>::append(a);
    }

    void myFunc()
    {
        qDebug() << T::staticMetaObject.className();
    }
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting you types confused.

You want `T` to be `MainWindow` so that you can do

```
T::staticMetaObject.className()
```

That means you want a `QList<T*>`. You derive from that so you can just call

```
append(a);
```

The following code compiles fine:

```
class FormBase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FormBase() {}
};

template <typename T>
class Form : public FormBase, public QList<T*>
{
public:
    Form( T* a )
    {
        append( a );
    }

    void myFunc()
    {
        qDebug() << T::staticMetaObject.className();
    }
};

class MainWindow:
    public QMainWindow
{
    MainWindow()
    {
        form = new Form<MainWindow>( this );
    }

    FormBase* form;
};
```

Comment: I dont know how you mean that. I do have to fill out <> or I get a compile error (expected specifier before Form). You are right the problem is that T is T* and thats why staticMetaObject is not working. But I dont understand your answer

Comment: then I get the error expected specifier before Form. I dont want this as parent, maybe you missundertsnad. I want it as an pointer in the List.

Comment: sry for that. Hope you dont missunderstand my example.

Comment: but then myFunc() does not work. class FormBase' has no member named 'myFunc'
     form->myFunc();
           ^

Comment: feel free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)